# Carbon dioxide vibration

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, vibrations, molecules, quantum-chemistry

Can we induce antisymmetric stretching vibration in carbon dioxide molecules by collision with nitrogen molecules in air at standard temperature and pressure?

Comment: I had an answer from vcuteym on 13 Feb followed by my comments however both of them have been deleted .Why?

Comment: You can check out the timeline of the answer (your comment and the justification of deletion by ACuriousMind) by opening the activity of the post.

Comment: I cannot find the justification of deletion by ACuriousMind

Comment: "I'm deleting this since it does not appear to answer the question."